# seiner selbst wegen

Tags: genitive

This part is from the introduction of *Aphorismen zur Lebensweisheit* by Arthur Schopenhauer:

> Ich nehme den Begriff der Lebensweisheit hier gänzlich im immanenten Sinne, nämlich in dem der Kunst, das Leben möglichst angenehm und glücklich durchzuführen, die Anleitung zu welcher auch Eudämonologie genannt werden könnte: sie wäre demnach die Anweisung zu einem glücklichen Dasein. Dieses nun wieder ließe sich allenfalls definiren als ein solches, welches, rein objektiv betrachtet, oder vielmehr (da es hier auf ein subjektives Urtheil ankommt) bei kalter und reiflicher Überlegung, dem Nichtsein entschieden vorzuziehn wäre.
> Aus diesem Begriffe desselben folgt, daß wir daran hingen, seiner selbst wegen, nicht aber bloß aus Furcht vor dem Tode; und hieraus wieder, daß wir es von endloser Dauer sehn möchten.

I cannot understand why there is -er in "seiner selbst". I know that "sein" refers to "das Dasein" and that "wegen" is used in a genitive structure, but have no idea why "selbst" is treated as a feminine noun here.

Comment: @DavidVogt It should. *Seiner* is simply the genitive of "sein". It's unclear to me where the OP sees a *feminine noun* here.

Comment: @tofro The other question had the same issue: native speakers not understanding what the problem was. But the genitive forms of personal pronouns are a topic that language learners encounter incredibly late. I just checked a practice grammar for the C1/C2 level and it notes laconically: *Personalpronomen im Genitiv werden heute kaum noch verwendet*, and goes on to ignore them. – Isn't it natural, then, that language learners mistake *seiner* for a possessive determiner with a missing feminine noun?

Comment: Some topics featuring genitive forms of personal pronouns: [1](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/49141/35111) [2](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/23949/35111) [3](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/54295/35111)

Comment: @DavidVogt Yes, I guess. But I need some time to fully grasp the idea. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to say *because of me* is *meinetwegen* (the dative common *wegen mir* is common but not correct). Analogously *seinetwegen* is *because of him*, or *because of oneself*. But here *selbst* emphasizes the *self* and separates this word, thus creating *seiner (selbst) wegen*.

Comment: Auf "wegen" folgt immer der Genitiv (zumindest habe ich das so gelernt). Es ist zwar allgemein üblich,  "wegen mir" zu sagen - aber richtig ist es nicht.

Comment: @KritikerderElche *wegen* habe ich nie selbst mit Dativ verwendet, höre ich aber auch nicht selten.

Answer (score 0):

Schopenhauer says that *(glückliches) Dasein* which translates as *(happy) existence* or *(happy) life* has to be preferred against *Nichtsein* which translates as *non-being* or *non-existence*. Therefore we are fond of "Dasein" *seiner selbst wegen*, i.e. *because of itself*. Here "seiner" has nothing to do with the verb "sein"; it is a prounoun in genitive which stands for "des Daseins".

Comment: I'm not talking about the verb, "sein".